# pre_match div with unwanted line breaks

Tags: wordpress, preg-match

I'm a noob when it comes to regex, and not so good with php either.

I used this code to copy contents from another url:

```
<?php

$conts = file_get_contents('http://www.curtisjohnsonrealtyaz.com');

$pattern = '~<div.*id="home-right".*>(.*?)</div>~iUs';
preg_match($pattern, $conts, $matches);
array_shift($matches);

echo $matches[0];

?>
```

It worked fine except for the additional line breaks and also replaced an anchored image link to the current url.

I really would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: "It worked fine except for the additional line breaks and also replaced an anchored image link to the current url."

I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "m" flag into your pattern, that should make it stretch across linebreaks (multiline mode).

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't know how to do it... What will be the new code look like?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... if you're still looking for the solution, I was suggesting doing this:
`$pattern = '~<div.*id="home-right".*>(.*?)</div>~iUsm';`
- adding the m into the matching flags

Answer (score 0):

You should be use a dom parser to parse html, [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is a good option.

Code:

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html('http://www.curtisjohnsonrealtyaz.com');
$div = $html->getElementById("home-right")->innertext;
echo $div;
```

PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser means less code and consistent results :)